# Require in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

The argument of `require(...)` in node.js is a filename. If I had a **module source code in a string** `code`, could I somehow call `require(code)` and load functions from that string?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules (what a ridiculous uri)

Comment: @jAndy Where is a source code in a string? I see only loading from file.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: @Martin ah sorry about that; I completely misread the question.  Well if you have the source, can't you just `eval()` it?

Comment: @Martin Maybe, but I would like to "load once", and call those functions "million times", is it optimal?

Comment: @Martin I see no reason why one could not define stuff inside an eval for later use, technically speaking. But why is it you have code in a string, anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around could be to write the module source code to a temporary file `./tmp-file.js` and then `require('./tmp-file')`, and then remove the file.

This is probably not optimal because you would either have to block and write the file synchronously, or put everything requiring that module in the callback to the async write.

A working example for async file write ([gist - also includes sync file write](https://gist.github.com/3438596)):

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var helloModuleString = "exports.world = function() { return 'Hello World\\n'; }";
fs.writeFile('./hello.js', helloModuleString, function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  var hello = require('./hello');

  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end(hello.world());
  }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
});
```

Results in:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:1337
> Hello World
```

Comment: In general I agree, but that requires the node app to be allowed to create a file on the file system. And if you start multiple instances of the node app you have to decide what to do with the file or namespace them somehow. I tried to add a custom extension, but that is deprecated now. Isn't there any other good solution?

Answer (score 2):

I put this into a function for reuse. It creates a file in the os temp directory based on a random hash, requires it and then deletes it.

```
var fs     = require('fs'),
    os     = require('os'),
    crypto = require('crypto');

function requireString(moduleString) {
  var token           = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex'),
      filename        = os.tmpdir() + '/' + token + '.js',
      requiredModule  = false;

  // write, require, delete
  fs.writeFileSync(filename, moduleString);
  requiredModule = require(filename);
  fs.unlinkSync(filename);

  return requiredModule;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var carString = "exports.start = function(){ console.log('start'); };",
    car       = requireString(carString);

console.log("Car:", car);
```

This is still more of a workaround, but more convenient to use, I think.